# SQL - filtering out entire rows to get rid of "placeholder" data

Tags: sql, group-by

The following query:

```
select
    dim.DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer,
    dim.VisitationId as VisitationsId,
    dim.BestillingId as BestillingId,
    dim.ServicePeriodeSlut as ServicePeriodeSlut
from nexus2.Dim_IndsatsDetaljer as dim
where DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer = '3803872' or DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer = '3803871'
```

Produces the following:

```
DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer   VisitationsId   BestillingId    ServicePeriodeSlut
3803871                 589682          589683          2019-09-23
3803872                 589682          589682          9999-12-31
```

From the source, I know that 9999-12-31 is a placeholder which exists until the system registers an actual date. So I DO need it, except in cases like this where another date was registered.
I can see from the VisitationsId, that it's the same transaction, so I don't need the placeholder *in this case*.
DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer is nothing more than a row Id, and BestillingId is generated when something happens in the Visitation.

So I believe that getting the max(bestillingId) is key here - but I'm not sure how to do what I need to?

Basically, I need to group by VisitationId, and find the max(BestillingId) and just take the date from that.
I've tried

```
select
    dim.DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer,
    dim.VisitationId as VisitationsId,
    max(dim.BestillingId) as BestillingId,
    dim.ServicePeriodeSlut as ServicePeriodeSlut
from nexus2.Dim_IndsatsDetaljer as dim
where DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer = '3803872' or DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer = '3803871'
group by    dim.DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer,
    VisitationId,
    ServicePeriodeSlut
```

which gives me the same result as above.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please just share your desired output.

Comment: before you do anything why don't simply use a `case when ServicePeriodeSlut = '9999-12-31' then null end as ServicePeriodeSlut` or other string that can easily filter out the placeholder value so `max` will work.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur the desired output is just the first line of the actual output

Comment: @T.Peter because I need the placeholder UNLESS another date has been entered. And it's always '9999-12-31' so changing it to null or another string is unnecessary

Comment: then create another column using `case` which have changed `ServicePeriodeSlut` for `max` and keep orgin column for inspect.

Comment: @T.Peter I don't need the MAX(ServicePeriodeSlut), I need the ServicePeriodeSlut for MAX(BestillingId)

Comment: Which dbms of what version u r using?

Answer (score 1):

I actually stumbled upon the answer myself:

```
select
x.DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer,
x.VisitationId,
max(x.BestillingId),
x.ServicePeriodeSlut
from (
        select
            f.VisitationId,
            max(f.BestillingId)
        from nexus2.Dim_IndsatsDetaljer as f
        group by VisitationId
    )

as y inner join nexus2.Dim_IndsatsDetaljer as x on x.VisitationId = y.VisitationId and x.BestillingId = y.BestillingId
```

So basically select what I need from the result of a simple query to get MAX(BestillingId) and joining the original table with that result. Worked like a charm, and wasn't very ressouce-heavy (the "real" code has a TON of columns, and more than just ServicePeriodeSlut that gave the problem).

Answer (score 0):

With row_number() window rank function you can select rows with max BestillingId  for each visitationid

```
with cte as 
(
select
    dim.DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer,
    dim.VisitationId as VisitationsId,
    dim.BestillingId as BestillingId,
    dim.ServicePeriodeSlut as ServicePeriodeSlut,
    row_number()over(partition by VisitationsId  order by BestillingId  desc)rn   
from nexus2.Dim_IndsatsDetaljer as dim
where DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer = '3803872' or DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer = '3803871'
)
select     dim.DW_SK_IndsatsDetaljer,    VisitationsId,    BestillingId, ServicePeriodeSlut  f
rom cte where rn=1
```

Comment: This works on the dummy data, I'm testing it now on the actual 10 mil rows I have, as well as another possiblity - will let you know how that goes in a bit

Comment: Please let me know if you face any difficutlites.